# Aligning three columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am wanting to have a layout like below - but I currently get the two `md` columns on the top

The `img` should be aligned in the middle Vertical and Horizontal of the container and the two `md` columns should be aligned with the centre of the `img`

I don't want a scroll

```
  `image div`
```

`mid-6`    `mid-6`

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="inner">
                     <img src="assets/img/logo.jpg" width="600" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
                </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">  
                    1

                    </div>  

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    2
                    </div>

             </div>

        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

.container{
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:100%;
}​

.inner { position: relative; }
.inner img { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jess, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/ZcAYA/) Take a look at my fiddle and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were asking on this, but I provide you two options which both should work as intended.

First one is to set up the image to be an **absolute** positioned element.

```
.inner img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20;
}
```

And the other one being the actual 3 columns, where you should add one **col-md** div to your HTML and change the **6** in each of them to **4**, as in Bootstrap the row width is 12 pts. You can also use your image in a separate row with just one column in it, and maybe use something like **margin-bottom: -25** to align it properly, which may break some responsiveness so it's not suggested to be the first thing you try on this.

Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: can i have a Example plz

Comment: Basically like [this (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvCBJ/), but of course it will look different when you put it to where bootstrap styles are applied. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to assign the col-md-12 class to the inner div?

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="inner col-md-12">
                 <img src="assets/img/logo.jpg" width="600" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">  
                1

                </div>  

                <div class="col-md-6">
                2
                </div>

         </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gr8 Escape

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="inner">
                         <img src="assets/img/logo.jpg" width="100" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">  
                        1

                        </div>  

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        2
                        </div>

                 </div>

            </div>
```

CSS

```
.col-md-6
{
    float: left;
    width:40px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.row
{
    margin-left:40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute is dangerous... try this:

```
.outer {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}
.inner {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

With

```
<div class="outer" style="height:300px"> <!-- height just to show v-centering -->
  <div class="inner" style="border:1px solid red"> !--
    <img src="//placehold.it/600x100">
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
        <div class="label label-default">1</div>
      </div>  
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
        <div class="label label-default">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**DEMO here: http://www.bootply.com/TMTdSQa8Bt#**